# SyntaxFactory generate constructor with calling base class constructor

Tags: c#, roslyn

I wrote code which generates a new class in accordance with an initial state.
Roslyn provides the class `SyntaxFactory` for it, but I don't understand how to generate a constructor by calling the base class, like this:

```
public TestClientApi(String entryPoint) : **base(entryPoint)**
{
    _entryPoint = entryPoint;
}
```

https://github.com/ddydeveloper/Roslyn.ApiClient.Codegen

Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create your constructor declaration with an initializer.

```
ConstructorDeclaration("TestClientApi")
    .WithInitializer(
        ConstructorInitializer(SyntaxKind.BaseConstructorInitializer)
                // could be BaseConstructorInitializer or ThisConstructorInitializer
            .AddArgumentListArguments(
                Argument(IdentifierName("entryPoint"))
            )
    )
    ...
```

Comment: BTW, this assumes you have a static using in your code file: `using static Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SyntaxFactory;`